# Github actions, schedule operation on branch

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I am trying to configure a github workflow, I have managed to configure it on push event. However what if I need it to run on after a time period has passed?

What I have understood from the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/configuring-a-workflow) is that it can be achieved using a schedule.

```
name: Release Management

on: 
  schedule:
   - cron: "*/5 * * * *"
```

How do I specify the branch that the action will run on ?

My end goal is to automate releases.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) you will see that the `GITHUB_SHA` associated with the `on: schedule` event is "Last commit on default branch." This is what will be checked out by default when you use the `actions/checkout` action.

If your repository's default branch is `master` (which in general is the case) this workflow will checkout the last commit on `master` when it triggers.

```
name: Release Management
on: 
  schedule:
   - cron: "*/5 * * * *"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

If you want to checkout a different branch you can specify with parameters on the checkout action. This workflow will checkout the last commit on the `some-branch` branch.

```
name: Release Management
on: 
  schedule:
   - cron: "*/5 * * * *"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: some-branch
```

See [documentation for the `actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action for other options.

Comment: Maybe there is still a subtle problem, if you don't allow the `master` branch to deploy the essential CI enviornment in repository setting, actions will fail.

Comment: specially annoying if you use the workflow both to trigger manually (that allows choosing branch) and schedule. You cannot hardcode a branch in the checkout step otherwise branch option when triggering manually makes no sense