# How do I trigger a scheduled action on a specific branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

I've made an action. I'd like for this to run on branch `foo` at a schedule(in my case, twice a day).

Here's what I've got so far:

`repo/.github/workflows/daily-foo-tests.yml`

```
name: Run integration tests on foo branch twice a day
on:
  schedule:
    # Execute at 00:01 and 13:01 UTC daily
    - cron:  '00 01,13 * * *'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Run UI Automation
    runs-on: [self-hosted, macOS, X64]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: dotnet build
        with: { ref: foo }
        // continues to do stuff, not important
```

Now, this action has been pushed to said `foo` branch. However, going to `github.com/org/repo/actions`, it does not trigger(I've waited 24 hours now; it should've done something at this point).

What is the correct way to trigger a scheduled github action workflow on a specified branch?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800550/11934042). Your workflow must be committed to the default branch to trigger `on: schedule`.

Comment: So, say `foo` is a the `staging` branch, and `master` is the default branch of the repository - the workflow yaml must exist on the `master` branch before anything is triggered? I don't want it to run on the latest commit SHA on the default branch; I want the latest commit sha on the `foo` branch.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `on: schedule` workflows do not work in non-default branches. But you can still checkout other branches when it runs.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, so I'll ask directly: Can I run a scheduled workflow on a non-default branch in any way? Is that the last part of the answer you sent me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The workflow must be committed to the default branch to be triggered. It won't work if you only commit it to a non-default branch.

> Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch.

ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule

For example, this should be committed to the default branch. When it runs, it checks out branch `foo` and then you can build, test, etc.

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 1 * * 4'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: foo
      
      # Build steps go here
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this solution. I'll accept it... within 12 hours, if green ;-)

Comment: If there any way to run this in two branches, e.g. default and foo? Of course I can write yml so that there are separate steps for each branch or implement separate yml file for each branch, but no simpler way to do it?

Comment: @diidu The only way I know to simplify that scenario is to use a [job matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) to avoid having duplicate steps for each branch.