# Run scheduled Github workflow only on a particular branch

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I am using this syntax to trigger workflow at the scheduled time only for prod branch.

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "11 0 * * SAT"
    branches:
      - prod
```

But when I push the code it shows a syntax error:

```
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 4
```

Any inputs? Does the schedule work with "branches" option?

Comment: As the error message says. You have a syntax error. `branches` is indented to the same level as `- cron`. It either needs to be moved back to the same level as `schedule` or prefixed with `- ` like the previous line, depending on what you are trying to do. (Then `- prod`) needs to be given the right level of indentation too.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a job on schedule, if you want to checkout your code, you have to use

> actions/checkout@v2

Check for this article [How do I trigger a scheduled action on a specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612155/how-do-i-trigger-a-scheduled-action-on-a-specific-branch)

`branches prod` make sense only when you use `on push` or `on pull_request`.