# Build in feature branch is not working using Cron schedule and API call GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions, github-api, cicd

We have a requirement to trigger GitHub Actions pipeline using API and Cron Schedule.
We have those changes in default branch and those are working fine but the same changes are not working when comes to feature branch.

Am i missing any config in Github ?

```
on: 
  schedule:
    - cron: '1 * * * *'
```

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer token"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo_name/dispatches \
  -d '{"event_type":"develop-package"}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github actions, schedule operation on branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798886/github-actions-schedule-operation-on-branch)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to trigger workflows by cron `schedule` event on branch different than default one (like fature branches). This is expected behaviour according to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule):

> Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit **on the default or base branch**.

This should answer the first part of your question. It's not possible to have an `on.schedule` event triggered on a branch different than your repo default branch. This is why it does not work for your feature branches.

Speaking about the second part of the question. You are trying to manually trigger the workflow by using [`repository_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) webhook event but it seems your workflow is not configured to be triggered this way.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch):

> When you make a request to create a `repository_dispatch` event, you must specify an `event_type` to describe the activity type. By default, all `repository_dispatch` activity types trigger a workflow to run. You can use the types keyword to limit your workflow to run when a specific `event_type` value is sent in the `repository_dispatch` webhook payload.

According to this, the missing part of your workflow configuration configuration is the  `repository_dispatch` event declaration:

```
on: 
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - develop-package
```

So, to be able to trigger the workflow run using both cron (`schedule` event) and manually using Github API (`repository_dispatch` event) you should have both events mentioned in the workflow triggers configuration:

```
on:
 schedule:
    - cron: '1 * * * *'
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - develop-package
```