# How to reuse a workflow from same repo in a scheduled github action and run it in the context for a specific branch?

Tags: github, github-actions, continuous-deployment

on a private github-repo i want to create a scheduled job in a `nightly-qa.yml`, which runs every night at 2 and should deploy my app to qa system (from the `develop` branch!). I have a cd.yml flow already and i want to reuse it. Since the scheduled job is per default running on the default branch (the main), the called workflow `cd.yml` with `use` is also running on the main side. But i want to call the `cd.yml` inside the branch `develop`. I also read the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798886/github-actions-schedule-operation-on-branch), but this forces me to move all the checkout actions into the `nightly-qa.yml`. I tried also the `<OWNER>/<REPO>/.github/workflows/cd.yml@develop` syntax, but this just use the workflow.yml version from the develop branch, but does not run in the context of the `develop` branch.

```
name: Nightly deployment of qa system
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '* 2 * * *'

jobs:

  deployment:
    permissions:
      contents: write
    name: Run CD Workflow
    secrets: inherit
    uses: <OWNER>/<REPO>/.github/workflows/cd.yml@develop
    with:
      config: qa
      version-bump-level: prerelease
```

I also tried the the following [Github Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch), where i can specify the ref attribute.

```
- name: Invoke workflow without inputs
  uses: benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1
  with:
    workflow: cd.yml
    ref: develop
```

But there i get the:

> Run benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1 /usr/bin/docker exec
> f7414c05443aa832a2b1ba0fd457593361b7ec6354f68d861746723554fab609 sh -c
> "cat /etc/*release | grep ^ID"  Workflow Dispatch Action v1.2.1
> Error: Resource not accessible by integration

I also tried calling [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) inside the pipeline, where i get the same error:

```
name: scheduled nightly build for qa
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '* 2 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted 
    name: deploy on qa and call the cd flow on development branch

    container: 
      image: alpine:3.19

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install curl
        run: apk update && apk add --no-cache curl
      - name: list available workflows
        env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
        run: | 
          curl -L \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/actions/workflows
      - name: Call cd
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
        run: |
          curl -L \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
        https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/actions/workflows/cd.yml/dispatches \
            -d '{"ref":"develop"}'
```

---

There i get the same error. It looks like permissions are missing in the token. I checked the permissions and i have configured this:

[image: here the current permission settings in the private repo]

What is currently a good approach to call a workflow and specify the branch ref, where it should be executed? In the end i just want to create nightly build from the state of the `develop` branch.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

*It would appear you are missing* `permissions.actions: write` on the job in the scheduled workflow in `main` that's trying to create the dispatch event.

### Triggering a `workflow_dispatch` that provides `context` objects.

I can trigger a `workflow_dispatch` in another branch with the calling workflow from `main`;

```yaml
name: "Caller"
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  # schedule:
  # - cron: '* 2 * * *'
permissions: {}
jobs:
  call:
    name: Call the callee in develop branch
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      actions: write
    steps:
    - name: Call dispatchable
      run: >-
        curl -L -X POST
        -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
        https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/callee.yml/dispatches
        -d '{"ref":"develop", "inputs":{"config":"qa","version-bump-level":"prerelease"}}'
```

And the workflow to be called (where a `workflow_dispatch`'able workflow of the same name lives in `main` *as well as* some other branch to be called in; although they don't need to have the same setup after that point, the API will first check for the existence of the file with that name in `main` and that it can be `workflow_dispatch`'ed);

```yaml
name: Callable
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      config:
        required: true
        type: string
        default: "something"
      version-bump-level:
        required: true
        type: string
        default: "something else"
jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - run: echo ${GITHUB_REF##*/}
    - run: echo ${{ inputs.config }}
    - run: echo ${{ inputs.version-bump-level }}
    - run: cat .github/workflows/callee.yml
```

Per the permissions you've granted in the screenshot (`read` for `contents` and `packages`) you'll need to specifically grant the `actions` scope a level of `write`, in the caller workflow, to give it permission to create the dispatch event.